# Achieve "Glitch" effect on android canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, visual-glitch

I've come across this effect in CSS http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/ypgql
I know the main part of the effect in CSS happens here

```
clip:rect(random(100)+px,9999px,random(100)+px,0);
```

It's known as a "glitch" effect.
I've been trying to achieve this same effect on android using the canvas.
I haven't been successful as of yet. I'm pretty familiar with the canvas and animating its properties. I just need help figuring out how to distort the text.
Thanks.

Comment: This is one of those questions that you'd be better off trying a bunch of stuff and coming back with what you get caught up on. I went to your link, changed the values in the `.glitch:before` and `.glitch:after` properties to slow it down and see what they were doing. Once I saw the effect slowed down it was pretty obvious what the for loops were doing to the "canvas"

Comment: I know what it's doing, I just don't know how to do it. In essence there is a slice or rect that is being translated a few pixels. I'm not looking for a code handout, just some guidance.